# Is $f(x,y) = \frac{x^ny^m}{x^{n'}+y^{m'}}$ continuous at origin?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let function $\,\, f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\,$ be defined as
$$
f(x,y) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \frac{x^ny^m}{x^{n'}+y^{m'}}\text{,} &\quad(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
       \text{0,} &\quad \text{otherwise}\\
     \end{cases}
$$
with $n,m,n',m' \in\mathbb{N}^*$ so that $n>n'$ or $m>m' $.
Then from previous examples I've analysed, I'd guess that $\,f$ is continous at $(0,0)$. But somehow I've got a feeling that this can't be true. (My feeling is caused by the sequence criterion. Suppose $n>n'$ and $m'>m$. If $y$ "shrinks a lot faster" in a given sequence, $\,f(x,y)$ should grow instead of converging to 0.)

**If** $\,\boldsymbol{f}$ **is continus at origin** could you either:

- proof it
- explain your intuition why this is true

**If** $\,\boldsymbol{f}$ **is not continus at origin** could you either:

- hint me a counter-example
- disproof the statement

Cheers,
Pascal

Comment: Do you have any other condition on the coefficients? Are they even or generics?

Comment: @gimusi This is just something I am curious about, not a test question or something similar. I thought of this without any other constraints. But if you tell me you could prove it if they are even, go ahead. (I'm glad about anything that points me in the right direction.)

Comment: @plauer Ah ok, there are duplicates, refer also to [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2912348/505767)

Comment: @gimusi Thank you. I feel like this one is a lot easier to understand. :)

Comment: You are welcome! Bye